# open dialer in ios on click of button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I tried following code but it is not working

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",@"55698"]]];
```

Please provide help which support iOS7 SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove // after tel: in your code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:55698"]];
```

OR

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",@"55698"]]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Above answers are fine. Still please log, you have some `Blank space`(`@" "`) left in front or back of the Phone number string. I was facing same problem and getting the error like this:

> LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme
>   (null)

Then I have added that code and Open the Prompt dialler like the Below code

```
NSString *strPhone=[[[dictEvent valueForKey:@"app_contact_value"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@",strPhone]]];
```

and now it is Running fine.

You can also directly call with phone number like other answers:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@",strPhone]]];
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this simple code:**

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://55698"];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

Try it out in device not in simulator...

Comment: Try this code in your device. You can't make any code in simulator.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2.0 - >= iOS 7.0  , you can use the following:

```
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://9809088798")!

    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url))
    {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
```

Comment: Swift works from iOS8 only. TheN why mentioned about >=iOS7.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can place a call through the phone app using

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"tel://472490168092";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

You cannot open the keypad within the phone app in iOS.You can design your own phone pad in your view controller, add tones for keys. That's the only way to achieve this AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `tel://`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:55698"]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Swift and iOS 10 and up, where phone number is a string

```
        //call Phone dialer
        if  let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)  {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
```